# How to retrieve passed params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails (4.1) app I call the method create_bound in several classes (the method is included in the  ExtModule).

The method takes 2 params: task_name and user_id

Is there a way to know which parameters the method is called with?

For instance having the code below

```
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExtModule

  ...

  create_bound("Buy Milk", 1)
  ...
end
```

**Update 1**

I have a second class called BoundRetriever

```
Class BoundRetriever

  def self.get_bound(klass)
   #Ruby magic happens here
  end
end
```

and `BoundRetriever.get_bound(Event)` should return ["Buy Milk", 1]

How can I define `get_bound` ?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: when you say: `include ModuleName` you have the methods available as instance methods in the class you include the module. So, why can't you call `create_bound("Buy Milk", self)`? which will send the `Event` class `object`? Do you have some other classes calling this method in your code?

Comment: Probably I wasn't clean enough, my bad. I need to know the params from a second object. See update 1

Comment: I am sorry. I still didn't understand. What do you mean by: 1 starting from the class `Event`?

Comment: Your `BoundRetriever` class will be a Ruby class or an `ActiveRecord::Base` class? Because, if you store the data for BoundRetriever in its table then you can just use associations for this scenario.

Comment: I'd rather using a simple ruby class

Comment: Then I hope you know that the data will not be available once you release the `Event` or any other class's object you use.

Comment: So, isn't it possibile?

Comment: it is. but the data won't persist for long. I mean you can not access it after you're done calling create_bound and call some other method, or create another Event instance etc.

Comment: That's not an issue. I just need the 2 params when I call ```get_bound```. The 2 params will be passed to an other method that verifies if the user is authorized to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of a `BoundRetriever` class there.

In your **ext_module.rb**:

```
module ExtModule
  BOUND = []

  def create_bound(task_name, some_id)
    BOUND.replace [task_name, some_id]
    # rest of the code goes here..
  end

  def get_bound
    BOUND
  end
end
```

and in your models, like **event.rb**, you can call:

```
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExtModule

  ...

  create_bound("Buy Milk", 1)
  ...

  # call get_bound with the same object
  get_bound #=> ["Buy Milk", 1]
  ...
end
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier on, I use create_bound in several classes (once in each one) and I need to be able to get the params in ```BoundRetriever``` for each one of them. Not sure your solution works in this case.

Comment: when you have create_bound in several classes, you'll have `get_bound` method for all those classes separately, as you have the constant for each and evert class in which you include `ExtModule`. However, if you explain me the situation that if you must use `BoundRetriever` class then I can think of some other way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. basically for each class that calls ```create_bound``` I need to know the user that is passed as param. ```BoundRetriever``` doesn't have to be used but I guess it is necessary.

Comment: I am sorry. I am confused now. How do you plan to use `get_bound`? in what conditions? and where in your code?

Comment: ```BoundRetriever.get_bound(Event)``` is going to return the bound for the class Event. From there I get the user in the bound such as ```user = user.find(BoundRetriever.get_bound(Event).last)``` (or similar) . The user than will be passed to an other object that performs some checks.  ```BoundRetriever``` has to work with different classes: Event, Project, Meeting

Comment: and why this can't be like this: `User.find(event.get_bound.last)` As, I'd already said, you won't have the access to data once you come out of `create_bound` method, but still can access it if you have the object, otherwise there's no other way. May you need to be little more clear with your requirement? :/